# posting to same URL but using 2 different functions

Tags: node.js, express

a portion of my application involves creating tests (i.e., picking x-number of questions from a filtered set of questions). The user is able to determine how big they want the test but to do so I need to calculate on the server how many questions are available. The function which creates the test is sent through this post:

```
app.post('/user/create_test', users.create_test);
```

As the user changes filters, I would like to determine the number of questions available... All I can think of is to use AJAX post to send the filter information but it will be passed to the same function as creating a test would... is there any way to post to the same URL but determine which function you execute?

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider creating another function. - The best way to do Restful API's.

   1. Consider renaming to `app.post('/user/test')`.
   2. The second function could be `app.post('/user/test/filters')`.
2. Or make a single POST request and make sure your function does both creating and filtering.

In general, the design of the app lacks maturity. Rethink the client-server communications.